# bigquery excel connector - query larger than 256 char

Tags: google-bigquery

I am unable to run a long query (280 char) in bq using the excel connector.

The developers guide says:

> Note: If your query is longer than 256 characters, Excel will not allow you to run the query. 
>   Split your query into parts and paste each of those parts in multiple adjacent cells.

I have tried splitting the one query but can't get this to work either posting into a cell beside or below.

Is there a way to make this work? I have run shorter queries fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

I've confirmed that placing multiple parts of the query in adjacent cells works fine.  I ran a query with a length of 757 characters on Excel for Mac 2011.

After placing your query in adjacent cells, you then need to define the query parameter value as a range, like this:

```
=Sheet1!$B$7:$B$11
```

FYI - the `len()` function in Excel comes in handy when doing this.

#### Old Response:

I've sent a note to the engineer who wrote that feature/doc.  Will let you know.

In the meantime (as a workaround), you should be able to open up a text editor and modify the .iqy file you've downloaded to include your query directly.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I had simply not used a range of cells.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code for this so-called connector because it is using an obscure Excel feature.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157482

Comment: The excel connector does have code-- because it handles proxying of the the requests from excel and doing the appropriate authorization handshaking.  It's an app engine app for handling the proxying.  The App Engine app is not open-sourced currently.