# How do I edit the BigQuery Connector for Excel .iqy file to have the SQL statement already in it instead of relying on input from an Excel cell?

Tags: sql, excel, syntax, google-bigquery, connector

I'm having an issue similar to [bigquery excel connector - query larger than 256 char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244446/bigquery-excel-connector-query-larger-than-256-char/49076107?noredirect=1#comment85160107_49076107)

However, I AM referencing a cell range and get the result:

```
"WARNING Request failed: Error. Unable to execute query. 400 { code : 400, errors : [ { domain : global, location : query, locationType : other, message : 1.593 - 1.593: No query found., reason : invalidQuery } ], message : 1.593 - 1.593: No query found. }"
```

Perhaps I'm "splitting" the query incorrectly? I assumed each cell only needed to be less than 256 characters, and it would just concatenate subsequent cells in the range specified to the end of the string in the preceding cells.

Every help document I've found show simple SQL statements, and I can run simple ones, but the query I really need to work has a select statement in the where clause for a field. I've tried joining the table referenced in the where clause to see if that makes the statement simpler, more easily recognizable as a query, but no luck.

I've tried opening the .iqy file in NotePad that (BigQuery originally had me download) to see if I could just input the query there, but I cannot find any documentation for syntax on these types of files so when I load it into Excel it still shows a prompt for the query to be inputted.

The final result doesn't need to have the query read from a cell reference, in fact, if it could all just be in the .iqy file, that would be most preferable: less chance of users mucking up the data.

Comment: Partial solution: Even though the Google BigQuery Connector directions page specified to add "#standardSQL" to force the Connector to use Standard SQL with the Connection instead of the default Legacy SQL--which that line does work in their web query composition page--I decided to try using Legacy. Once I ported it to the Legacy syntax and copied it into the cells, it worked as advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure to URL encode the parameters (`query`, `project` and `key`) in `.iqy` file. Use an online tool like https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder
2. if you had the `.iqy` loaded already in Excel before making above changes, you must delete the query definition. Go in `Properties` and uncheck `Save query definition`, then connect to the `.iqy` again

Not sure what the max size for `q`(query) is for https://bigquery-connector.appspot.com but I recommend using a BigQuery VIEW instead.

- it hides the SQL plumbing and hence reduces the size of the SQL passed to the API. URL encoding the query can then be as easy as replacing `spaces` with `+`
- you can tune/change the view definition in BigQuery without having to rollout a new `.iqy` to your users
- implement some sort of row-level security using `CURRENT_USER()`...

But that's another topic !

Finally, coming back to the `.iqy`, you can combine and embed parameters in the query like so:

```
q=select+*+from+mydataset.myview+where+FiscalYear=["Year", "Enter a year:"]&p=myproject&k=myURLencodedKey
```